What visa do I need if I want to do an internship at a hospital in Germany?
I'm a doctor from a non-EU country and planning to do an internship at a hospital in Germany.

Which visa do I need? (I think I cannot use tourist visa for this. Probably D visa but I'm not sure.)
Does the required visa change if the internship is paid or unpaid?
Will I need an "invitation letter" from the hospital, to show at the embassy before they will issue my visa? Where can I find information on what this letter should contain? (I assume it's important to use proper wording to increase chances of being approved.)
Something else am I not thinking of right now?

Thank you very much in advance.

How long will your internship be? A Schengen visa is not a tourist visa, it's a short-stay visa and covers many other purposes (including attending courses, getting medical treatment, etc.) So the duration of stay the main difference between a long-stay (type D) or Schengen (type C) visa. That said, even if they last less than 90 days, I think most internships do require some sort of work authorisation. I do not recall all the details but IIRC only some academic internships are exempt.

What did the hospital say when you asked them?
